# change string to customize format on SQL

Tags: sql

I have string format saved on table.the format like this -

```
`11/Apr/2014 2:30:00 PM-11/Apr/2014 4:00:00 PM`.
```

Using this format I want to return customize format while running stored procedure. The format should be-

```
`9.00 AM To 10.00 AM`.
```

This is what I'm trying :

```
SUBSTRING(LeaveManagement.EmployeeLeaveTransaction.Period, 12, 5) +
SUBSTRING(LeaveManagement.EmployeeLeaveTransaction.Period, 20, 3) + 
' To ' + 
SUBSTRING(LeaveManagement.EmployeeLeaveTransaction.Period, 36, 5) +
SUBSTRING(LeaveManagement.EmployeeLeaveTransaction.Period, 44, 3)
```

but it returns the wrong format if original string have

`11/Apr/2014 12:30:00 PM-11/Apr/2014 4:00:00 PM`

Can anyone help me to do this.i am trying using this query

Answer (score 0):

This query will be helpful to get the expected result in **SQL SERVER**.

```
DECLARE @Date AS VARCHAR(100)

SET @Date = '11/Apr/2014 1:30:00 PM-11/Apr/2014 2:00:00 PM'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Date, CHARINDEX(' ', @Date), CHARINDEX('-', @Date) - CHARINDEX(' ', @Date)) 
        + ' To ' 
        + Reverse(Substring(REVERSE(@Date), 0, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(@Date)) - 5))
```

Use this query:

```
SUBSTRING(LeaveManagement.EmployeeLeaveTransaction.Period, 
  CHARINDEX(' ', LeaveManagement.EmployeeLeaveTransaction.Period), 
    CHARINDEX('-', LeaveManagement.EmployeeLeaveTransaction.Period) 
    - CHARINDEX(' ', LeaveManagement.EmployeeLeaveTransaction.Period)) 
+ ' To ' 
+ Reverse(Substring(REVERSE(LeaveManagement.EmployeeLeaveTransaction.Period), 
    0, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(LeaveManagement.EmployeeLeaveTransaction.Period)) - 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SEELCT substr(COL_NAME,instr(COL_NAME,' ',1,1)+1,5)||
       substr(COL_NAME,instr(COL_NAME,' ',1,2),3)  ||
       ' TO '                                      ||
       substr(COL_NAME,instr(COL_NAME,' ',1,3),5)  ||
       substr(COL_NAME,instr(COL_NAME,' ',1,4),3)  
FROM   table_name
```